# Http error code 401 when I try to access a non login servlet

Tags: windows, http, servlets, service

I access a non login servlet from my web browser, it responses as expected. I try to access the same servlet using the [WinINet Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the parent process is windows service and the service is running under 'Local System Account'. I got the response in most of the machines, but results the error code 401 in few machines. But I could not reproduce in another machine. What would be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

401 Unauthorized:

> If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the
>   401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials.

The parent process is windows service and the service is running under
'Local System Account'.

It may happen if 'Local System Account' has not permission to execute the service.